# Segregating filtered tweets based on matched keywords : Twitter4j API

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have created twitter stream filtered by some keywords as follows.

```
TwitterStream twitterStream = getTwitterStreamInstance();
FilterQuery filtre = new FilterQuery();
String[] keywordsArray = { "iphone", "samsung" , "apple", "amazon"};
filtre.track(keywordsArray);
twitterStream.filter(filtre);
twitterStream.addListener(listener);
```

What is the best way to segregate tweets based on keywords matched. e.g. All the tweets that matches "iphone" should be stored into "IPHONE" table and all the tweets that matches "samsung" will be stored into "SAMSUNG" table and so on. NOTE: The no of filter keywords is about 500.

Comment: You've to loop through keywords and check if tweet contains keyword. You will get a single stream from twitter, no differentiation possible there.

Comment: Yes, but here keyword matching is not just based on simple comparison! It is more complicated search because keyword might have more than one words in it. Twitter4j has track method https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track for filtering which considers many parameters for keyword matching. If I find the code for search what they are using then I can use it directly. If not then I have to write whole code from scratch.

Comment: what do you mean by a table? Mysql?

Comment: @Nicool what do you mean by putting it in a table?

Comment: Yes, database table. The main goal is the mapping of the tweet to a search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only way to find out to which keyword a tweet belongs to is iterating over multiple properties of the `Status` object. The following code requires a database service with a method `insertTweet(String tweetText, Date createdAt, String keyword)` and every tweet is stored in the database multiple times, if multiple keywords are found. If at least one keyword is found in the tweet text, the additional properties are not searched for more keywords.

```
// creates a map of the keywords with a compiled pattern, which matches the keyword
private Map<String, Pattern> keywordsMap = new HashMap<>();
private TwitterStream twitterStream;
private DatabaseService databaseService; // implement and add this service

public void start(List<String> keywords) {
    stop(); // stop the streaming first, if it is already running

    if(keywords.size() > 0) {
        for(String keyword : keywords) {
            keywordsMap.put(keyword, Pattern.compile(keyword, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
        }

        twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                insertTweetWithKeywordIntoDatabase(status);
            }
            /* add the unimplemented methods from the interface */
        };
        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
        filterQuery.track(keywordsMap.keySet().toArray(new String[keywordsMap.keySet().size()]));
        filterQuery.language(new String[]{"en"});

        twitterStream.filter(filterQuery);
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Could not start querying because there are no keywords.");
    }
}

public void stop() {
    keywordsMap.clear();
    if(twitterStream != null) {
        twitterStream.shutdown();
    }
}

private void insertTweetWithKeywordIntoDatabase(Status status) {
    // search for keywords in tweet text
    List<String> keywords = getKeywordsFromTweet(status.getText());

    if (keywords.isEmpty()) {
        StringBuffer additionalDataFromTweets = new StringBuffer();

        // get extended urls
        if (status.getURLEntities() != null) {
            for (URLEntity url : status.getURLEntities()) {
                if (url != null && url.getExpandedURL() != null) {
                    additionalDataFromTweets.append(url.getExpandedURL());
                }
            }
        }

        // get retweeted status -> text
        if (status.getRetweetedStatus() != null && status.getRetweetedStatus().getText() != null) {
            additionalDataFromTweets.append(status.getRetweetedStatus().getText());
        }
        // get retweeted status -> quoted status -> text
        if (status.getRetweetedStatus() != null && status.getRetweetedStatus().getQuotedStatus() != null
                && status.getRetweetedStatus().getQuotedStatus().getText() != null) {
            additionalDataFromTweets.append(status.getRetweetedStatus().getQuotedStatus().getText());
        }
        // get retweeted status -> quoted status -> extended urls
        if (status.getRetweetedStatus() != null && status.getRetweetedStatus().getQuotedStatus() != null
                && status.getRetweetedStatus().getQuotedStatus().getURLEntities() != null) {
            for (URLEntity url : status.getRetweetedStatus().getQuotedStatus().getURLEntities()) {
                if (url != null && url.getExpandedURL() != null) {
                    additionalDataFromTweets.append(url.getExpandedURL());
                }
            }
        }

        // get quoted status -> text
        if (status.getQuotedStatus() != null && status.getQuotedStatus().getText() != null) {
            additionalDataFromTweets.append(status.getQuotedStatus().getText());
        }
        // get quoted status -> extended urls
        if (status.getQuotedStatus() != null && status.getQuotedStatus().getURLEntities() != null) {
            for (URLEntity url : status.getQuotedStatus().getURLEntities()) {
                if (url != null && url.getExpandedURL() != null) {
                    additionalDataFromTweets.append(url.getExpandedURL());
                }
            }
        }

        String additionalData = additionalDataFromTweets.toString();
        keywords = getKeywordsFromTweet(additionalData);
    }

    if (keywords.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: No Keyword found for: " + status.toString());

    } else {
        // insert into database
        for(String keyword : keywords) {
            databaseService.insertTweet(status.getText(), status.getCreatedAt(), keyword);
        }
    }

}

// returns a list of keywords which are found in a tweet
private List<String> getKeywordsFromTweet(String tweet) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String keyword : keywordsMap.keySet()) {
        Pattern p = keywordsMap.get(keyword);
        if (p.matcher(tweet).find()) {
            result.add(keyword);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd use a `StatusListener` to interrogate the received `Status` objects:

```
final Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<String>();
keywords.add("apple");
keywords.add("samsung");
// ...

final StatusListener listener = new StatusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onStatus(Status status) {
        final String statusText = status.getText();
        for (String keyword : keywords) {
            if (statusText.contains(keyword)) {
                dao.insert(keyword, statusText);
            }
        }
    }
};

final TwitterStream twitterStream = getTwitterStreamInstance();
final FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
fq.track(keywords.toArray(new String[0]));
twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

I see the DAO being defined along the lines of:

```
public interface StatusDao {
    void insert(String tableSuffix, Status status);
}
```

You would then have a DB table corresponding with each keyword. The implementation would use the `tableSuffix` to store the `Status` in the correct table, the sql would roughly look like:

```
INSERT INTO status_$tableSuffix$ VALUES (...)
```

#### Notes:

1. This implementation would insert a `Status` into multiple tables if a Tweet contained 'apple' and 'samsung' for instance.
2. Additionally, this is quite a naive implementation, you might want to consider batching inserts into the tables... but it depends on the volume of Tweets you'll be receiving.
3. As noted in the comments, the API considers other attributes when matching e.g. URLs and an embedded Tweet (if present) so searching the status text for a keyword match may not be sufficient.

Comment: This will only work partially, because the Twitter API does not only search through the tweet, but also through a retweetet tweet, expanded URLs (they are shortened in the tweet itself) and so on. My current workaround does already contain a search through the tweet and these properties, but I cannot be sure that I searched through all relevant properties.

Comment: Example tweet in a lookup for "trump": "He is wrong. See: t.co/SOMELINK". Here the word trump is inside the link and the tweet is still found by twitter.

Comment: I see, the `statusText.contains(keyword)` guard is not sufficient as other attributes may contain the keyword you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create a class similar to an ArrayList but make it so you can create an array of ArrayLists, call it TweetList. This class will need an insert function.

Then use two for loops to search through the tweets and find matching keywords that are contained in a normal array list, and then add them to the TweetList that matches the index of the keyword in the keywords ArrayList

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++)
           {
               String[] split = tweets[i].split(" ");// split the tweet up
               for (int j = 0; j < split.length; j++)
                   if (keywords.contains(split[j]))//check each word against the keyword list
                       list[keywords.indexOf(j)].insert[tweets[i]];//add the tweet to the tree index that matches index of the keyword
           }
```

Comment: This will only work partially, because the Twitter API does not only search through the tweet, but also through a retweetet tweet, expanded URLs (they are shortened in the tweet itself) and so on. My current workaround does already contain a search through the tweet and these properties, but I cannot be sure that I searched through all relevant properties.

Comment: Example tweet in a lookup for "trump": "He is wrong. See: t.co/SOMELINK". Here the word trump is inside the link and the tweet is still found by twitter.